# How to find a specific text from a column that a set of comma separated values in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-forms

I have a column like this

[image]

Now I know the set of values. Like someone was asked about 'Sports' and he/she had the below choices:
Cricket 
Tennis 
Football 
Others

Now the values that you see in any cell of the column apart from 'Cricket', 'Tennis' or 'Football' are entered as 'Others'

So I want the output in this manner that will only fetch what has been put as 'Others' and where it was not chosen it will be '0' (zero)
[image]

But if you see I was taking about 'Others' as an example. For this example, there is no such letter as 'Others', instead of there are 'I dont like any sports' or 'Playing sports was good at home' etc which can be anything followed by. So I want to show anything that doesn't match with 'Cricket', 'Football' or 'Tennis'

I'm a very novice at Excel and kind of doing this first time. Can anyone help what formula should I write at the starting of B column?

Answer (score 0):

Enter this as a function in the first row in your B column and pull it down for all your rows:

```
=IF(A1="Others";A1;0)
```

If you pull it down correctly, then the row below it should read `=IF(A2="Others";A2;0)`, rinse and repeat for all rows below. All cells in the B column should now either show "Others" or 0.

This is a simple IF statement in Excel and should be read as:

```
=IF(A1="Others";A1;0)
```

Or in pseudo-code:

```
IF A1 EQUALS "Others" THEN B1 EQUALS A1 ELSE B1 EQUALS 0
```

You can also replace the A1 and 0 in your formula by anything you like, e.g. you can set it to true and false by changing it to `=IF(A1="Others";true;false)`.

I don't know what you are planning to use it for, but you can also just set a filter at the top row, and filter out every cell which does not contain "Others". When working with large Excel-files, filters are your friend.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But if you see I was taking about 'Others' as an example.
For this example, there is no such letter as 'Others', instead of there are 'I dont like any sports' or 'Playing sports was good at home' etc which can be anything followed by.

So I want to show anything that doesn't match with 'Cricket', 'Football' or 'Tennis'.